# Applying Style To All Links In The Control

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink, menu, coding-style

I've got a div called 'menu' and inside that menu there are some divs and inside them there are hyperlinks.

I have a class for 'menu' and I also want a class to apply to all of my hyperlinks a certain height and width.

I tried `.MenuDiv a{}` but it didn't work

Comment: surely you need a space between `menu` and `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

.Menu div a
{
...
}

Answer (score 1):

You might alredy know this ;p

But if our class is "menu" you cant use ".MenuDiv".

Css for the links if it is an class:

.menu a{width:600px;height:200px}

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
<a href="#">link3</a>
</div>
```

It will also work if you have:

```
<div class="menu">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<a href="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
<a href="#">link3</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```